# How to move a div away from mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a landing page, in which I want my logo to move when followed by a mouse cursor which means I want to move it away from the direction of mouse, but it is just moving randomly and not in a precise way.

It's just a html page and I can use any open source, preferred javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>.container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px #000 solid;
        position: relative;
      }
      .box {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px #000 solid;
        position: absolute;
        right: 200px;
        background: red;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).box;
    $(this).css('position','absolute').css('top', Math.random()*200 + 'px').css('left', Math.random()*200 + 'px');
    });
    });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want it to be followed by the cursor precisely.

Comment: The question isn't really clear.  Do you want your logo to follow the mouse cursor exactly?  If you do then you can use CSS to use an image for the mouse cursor, if that helps?

Comment: I did something like this check here:https://jsfiddle.net/3fkn7chz/1/

Comment: @Archer i want the div to move in like opposite magnetic effect with cursor.

Comment: I think you need to just search for a library that will give you the effect you need.  It sounds like this will be a case of someone offering you code and you saying "but it needs to do this too..." and will continue in that manner.  Stack Overflow is for specific code issues - not general code requests.

Comment: @לבנימלכה this is now working for my job

Comment: @Archer with the code i have mentioned above the div is moving randomly but i want an effect where the div moves in the opposite direction.

Comment: That's too vague.  Try to do what you're asking and then maybe we can help, but what you have posted has nothing to do with what you're trying to describe.  It just randomly moves a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the position of the element (left, top, right and bottom).

Then use mouse coordinates to calculate the closest edge and move the box.

Here is an example of how you would do it. You can configure it according to your needs.

Check the working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".box-bounds" ).mouseenter(function(e) {
    closestEdge(e, this);
  });  
});

function moveDiv(mouse, edge, elem) {
  const width = $(elem).outerWidth();
  const height = $(elem).outerHeight();
  
  switch (edge) {
    case "left":
      $(elem).css({
       left: mouse.pageX + 5
      });
      break;
    case "right":
      $(elem).css({
       left: mouse.pageX - width - 20
      });
      break;
    case "top":
      $(elem).css({
       top: mouse.pageY + 5
      });
      break;
    case "bottom":
      $(elem).css({
       top: mouse.pageY - height - 20
      });
      break;
  }
}

function closestEdge(mouse, elem) {
  let elemBounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  let elementLeftEdge = elemBounding.left;
  let elementTopEdge = elemBounding.top;
  let elementRightEdge = elemBounding.right;
  let elementBottomEdge = elemBounding.bottom;

  let mouseX = mouse.pageX;
  let mouseY = mouse.pageY;

  let topEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementTopEdge - mouseY);
  let bottomEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementBottomEdge - mouseY);
  let leftEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementLeftEdge - mouseX);
  let rightEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementRightEdge - mouseX);

  let min = Math.min(topEdgeDist,bottomEdgeDist,leftEdgeDist,rightEdgeDist);

  let position;

  switch (min) {
    case leftEdgeDist:
      position = "left";
      break;
    case rightEdgeDist:
      position = "right";
      break;
    case topEdgeDist:
      position = "top";
      break;
    case bottomEdgeDist:
      position = "bottom";
      break;
  }
  
  moveDiv(mouse, position, elem);
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: relative;
}

.box-bounds {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  right: 200px;
  background: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div class="box-bounds">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```