# onMouseEnter Event in React not Working Perfectly

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

In my React App, I'm to implement a component that keeps changing position as soon as the mouse hovers on the element. I tried doing this using onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave but what I'm getting is not my expected result. The position of my element should keep changing anytime the cursor hovers on it but I was able to implement this for the first hover alone. My Code Below.

Hover.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Hover extends Component {
  state = {
    hovered: false,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="app"
        onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ hovered: true })}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ hovered: false })}
      >
        {this.props.children(this.state.hovered)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hover
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Hover from "./Hover";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="">
    <Hover>
      {(hovered) => (
        <h2
          className="content"
          style={
            hovered
              ? {
                  backgroundColor: "blue",
                 
                  marginLeft: "29rem",
                  marginTop: "15rem",
                  marginRight: "20rem",
                }
              : {
                  backgroundColor: "yellow",
                  // marginLeft: "20rem",
                  // marginTop: "9rem",
                }
          }
        >
          Move Your Cursor Closer{" "}
        </h2>
      )}
    </Hover>
  </div>
  );
}
```

Style.css

```
.app{
  display: flex;
}
.content{
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  
}
```

Comment: What you expecting on 2nd hover. Should it go further way from current position and what about mouseout, Should it go back to its original position.

Comment: The position should keep changing from its initial state as soon as the cursor hovers on it. the position could be anywhere. it just has to keep changing

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439658/how-to-move-a-div-away-from-mouse#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=First%20use%20getBoundingClientRect()%20to,edge%20and%20move%20the%20box.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your point, but try adding `pointer-events: none;` to your target element as a css property.